# {{ }} doesn't work inside for loop in laravel blade file

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, laravel-livewire

Here is my code:

```php
@for($var=0; $var<$count; $var++)
  {{ $count }}
@endfor
```

Here is the error it displays:

> syntax error, unexpected '}' (View: ...)

and it works fine when I remove `{{ $count }}`

Update:

I get the $count from the livewire php file, but even when I put `{{}}` empty the error comes. It never occurred to me, I have a lot of components and php files and used foreach on all of them and it worked perfect.

It also works when I use the `{{$count}}` outside the for loop. its strange.

Comment: Is that the sole content of that loop? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Does the template file contain more, maybe an opening `<?php` tag?

Comment: Please share more details, like the **full** content of the file triggering this error

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Solomon! Share also you component class so we can be able to help you.

Comment: This code is perfectly fine. Therefore, the issue must be somewhere else. Like others above have already mentioned, we require more insight to know where the issue might be.

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1: Add a tag around {{ }}. `<p>{{ $count}}</p>`

Solution 2: Add `@` symbol `@{{ $count }}`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should that resolve the problem? Also, `@` won't suppress a syntax error